# Find the eigenvalues of $A^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
    4       & 0 & 1 \\
    -2       & 1 & 0 \\
    -2       & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

I have found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda_{1} = 1$, $\lambda_{2} = 2$, $\lambda_{3} = 3$. How do I find the eigenvalues of $A^{3}$?

Answer (score 11):

Hint: for an eigenvector $x$ of A

$A^3 x=AAAx=AA\lambda x =\dots = \lambda^3 x$.